# How to capture a stdout of a specific function invocation?

Tags: node.js

We can capture stdout output by tapping into the `process.stdout.write`, e.g.

```
let output = '';

const originalStdoutWrite = process.stdout.write.bind(process.stdout);

process.stdout.write = (chunk, encoding, callback) => {
  if (typeof chunk === 'string') {
    output += chunk;
  }

  return originalStdoutWrite(chunk, encoding, callback);
};

console.log('foo');
console.log('bar');
console.log('baz');

process.stdout.write = originalStdoutWrite;
```

This is how the [`output-interceptor`](https://github.com/gajus/output-interceptor) and similar modules are implemented.

However, this approach does not work in a asynchronous/ concurrent environment, e.g.

```
const createOutputInterceptor = require('output-interceptor').createOutputInterceptor;
const delay = require('delay');

const interceptOutput = createOutputInterceptor();

const run = async (domain) => {
  await interceptOutput(async () => {
    console.log(domain, 1);

    await delay(Math.random() * 1000);

    console.log(domain, 2);    
  });

  console.log('"%s" domain captured output:', domain, JSON.stringify(interceptOutput.output));
};

run('foo');
run('bar');
run('baz');
```

As expected, this would produce arbitrary result:

```
"bar" domain captured output: "bar 1\n"
"baz" domain captured output: "baz 1\nbar 2\n"
"foo" domain captured output: "foo 1\n"
```

Is there a way to override `process.stdout` only in a context of a specific callback/ Promise execution?

I wondering if there is magic similar to [Domain](https://nodejs.org/api/domain.html) that could be used to achieve such result.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I have answered my own question by suggesting to use [Domain](https://nodejs.org/api/domain.html).

The trick is to override `process.stdout.write` and check for `process.domain`. If `process.domain` can be recognised as a domain that we have created with intent to capture the stdout, then we attach the `stdout` chunk to that domain, e.g.

```
const createDomain = require('domain').create;

const originalStdoutWrite = process.stdout.write.bind(process.stdout);

process.stdout.write = (chunk, encoding, callback) => {
  if (
    process.domain &&
    process.domain.outputInterceptor !== undefined &&
    typeof chunk === 'string'
  ) {
    process.domain.outputInterceptor += chunk;
  }

  return originalStdoutWrite(chunk, encoding, callback);
};

const captureStdout = async (routine) => {
  const domain = createDomain();

  domain.outputInterceptor = '';

  await domain.run(() => {
    return routine();
  });

  const output = domain.outputInterceptor;

  domain.outputInterceptor = undefined;

  return output;
};
```

Here is a fully working example:

```
const createDomain = require('domain').create;
const delay = require('delay');

const originalStdoutWrite = process.stdout.write.bind(process.stdout);

process.stdout.write = (chunk, encoding, callback) => {
  if (
    process.domain &&
    process.domain.outputInterceptor !== undefined &&
    typeof chunk === 'string'
  ) {
    process.domain.outputInterceptor += chunk;
  }

  return originalStdoutWrite(chunk, encoding, callback);
};

let domainIndex = 0;

const captureStdout = async (routine) => {
  const domain = createDomain();

  domain.outputInterceptor = '';

  await domain.run(() => {
    return routine();
  });

  const output = domain.outputInterceptor;

  domain.outputInterceptor = undefined;

  return output;
};

const run = async (domainName) => {
  process.stdout.write(domainName + ' domain 0\n');

  await delay(Math.random() * 100);

  process.stdout.write(domainName + ' domain 1\n');

  await delay(Math.random() * 100);

  process.stdout.write(domainName + ' domain 2\n');
};

const main = async () => {
  console.log('<><><> 0');

  const result1 = captureStdout(() => {
    return run('foo');
  });

  console.log('<><><> 1');

  const result2 = captureStdout(() => {
    return run('bar');
  });

  console.log('<><><> 2');

  const result3 = captureStdout(() => {
    return run('bar');
  });

  console.log('<><><> 3');  

  await Promise.all([
    result1,
    result2,
    result3,
  ]);

  console.log(
    result1,
    result2,
    result3
  );
};

main();
```

The above example will produce output:

```
<><><> 0
foo domain 0
<><><> 1
bar domain 0
<><><> 2
bar domain 0
<><><> 3
foo domain 1
bar domain 1
bar domain 1
foo domain 2
bar domain 2
bar domain 2
Promise { 'foo domain 0\nfoo domain 1\nfoo domain 2\n' } Promise { 'bar domain 0\nbar domain 1\nbar domain 2\n' } Promise { 'bar domain 0\nbar domain 1\nbar domain 2\n' }
```

I have since updated [`output-interceptor`](https://github.com/gajus/output-interceptor) module to use a variation of the above logic.